# Transform named list of tables into data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a named `list` of `table`s like this:

```
# make this simple and reproducible
set.seed(1)
days <- c("mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun")

# create list of tables
mylist <- list(
  one = table(sample(days, 3, replace = TRUE)),
  two = table(sample(days, 5, replace = TRUE)),
  three = table(NULL),
  four = table(sample(days, 4, replace = TRUE))
)

    mylist
#$one
#
#fri tue wed 
#  1   1   1 
#
#$two
#
#fri sun tue 
#  1   3   1 
#
#$three
#< table of extent 0 >
#
#$four
#
#fri mon tue 
#  1   1   2
```

And I would like to transform it into this `data.frame` where all the original list elements are rows in the resulting `data.frame`:

```
mydf
#      mon tue wed fri sun
#one     0   1   1   1   0
#two     0   1   0   1   3
#three   0   0   0   0   0
#four    1   2   0   1   0

# In this case I cheated and created it manually (order of columns is not important, order of rows is ideally preserved):
mydf <- data.frame(
  mon = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
  tue = c(1, 1, 0, 2),
  wed = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
  fri = c(1, 1, 0, 1),
  sun = c(0, 3, 0, 0)
)
rownames(mydf) <- c("one", "two", "three", "four")
```

I'm aware this is probably a non-standard transformation - is there any way to do this?

**EDIT:**
It might be relevant to know that the raw data would look something like this: `raw <- c("one:tue,wed,fri", "two:fri,sun,sun,tue,sun", "three", "four:tue,mon,tue,fri")`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include an example of your raw data as well?

Comment: How was `mylist` generated? Is it a given or can you interfere on a previous step in order to get your result? Does `mylist` result from an `apply(x, 2, table)` call? I guess that could be avoided as a whole.

Comment: The raw data would look something like this: raw <- c("one:tue,wed,fri", "two:fri,sun,sun,tue,sun", "three", "four:tue,mon,tue,fri")

Comment: Using your `raw` data, you could try something like `with(read.table(text = raw, sep = ":", fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = ""), table(stack(setNames(strsplit(V2, ",", TRUE), V1))))`

Comment: @alexis_laz Thank you! I ended up using a slightly modified version of your solution as it was the simplest and fastest: `dat <- read.table(text = raw, sep = ":", fill = TRUE, na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE); dat <- as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(dat$V2, ",", TRUE), dat$V1)))))` Happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: @enricoferrero : Glad I could help. Feel free to post as answer the modification that exactly worked for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @alexis_laz comment I ended up using this solution:

```
dat <- read.table(text = raw, sep = ":", fill = TRUE, na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat <- as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(dat$V2, ",", TRUE), dat$V1)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(mylist, as.data.frame.list), fill=TRUE)
```

---

Or using `melt/acast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(melt(mylist), L1~Var1, value.var="value", fill=0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've realised my real-world example is more complex and I've updated my question to reflect that: can you have a look and see if you know a solution that would work in this case too (i.e.: original list contains empty elements)?

Comment: @enricoferrero  In that case try `un1 <- unique(names(unlist(setNames(mylist, NULL)))); mylist1 <- lapply(mylist, function(x) if(length(x)==0) as.table(setNames(rep(0, length(un1)), un1)) else x); acast(melt(mylist1), L1~Var1, value.var="value", fill=0)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mylist2 <- mylist %>%
  lapply(., function(i) spread(as.data.frame(i), Var1, Freq)) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate_all(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)))
```

Result:

```
> mylist2
  fri mon tue sun wed thu
1   1   1   1   0   0   0
2   0   1   0   1   3   0
3   1   0   1   0   0   2
```

Comment: Thank you! I've realised my real-world example is more complex and I've updated my question to reflect that: can you have a look and see if you know a solution that would work in this case too (i.e.: original list contains empty elements)?

Comment: Have you tried taking what was done in the answers and seeing if you can extend it to the new version yourself? What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Your solution returns an error with the current data (Error: Key column 'Var1' does not exist in input.). You can use as.data.frame.list() instead of spread(as.data.frame()) to get rid of that but the problem is that the output will not include rows that are empty list elements. Maybe this solution can't be extended?

Comment: You could solve this problem with an `if/else` construct in the call to `lapply` that creates what amounts to a dummy row for NULL tables. But that's really a separate problem, and it's not great form to revise the question after you get answers to extend them to a new question.